# Using the virsh# command to delete an existing VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a been working on a Centos7 Box with a couple of VMs installed, I know how to use the `virsh#`  command to list, start or powerOff all existing VMs, However, I will like to know how to actually remove the VM with the `virsh#` command. Is there Such functionality. My problem is that I manually deleted a couple VMs a while ago. But when I use the `virsh#` command to list all existing VMs, those deleted VMs are appearing on the list as well. Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a VM's configuration by using the `virsh undefine` command. Note that this will not remove any storage unless you pass the arguments to do so, and this will not immediately remove any currently running VMs - they will be converted to transient and later removed after they're stopped.

See also, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-virsh-delete.html